# Dropdown menu for navigation on site HTML and CSS only

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

Here is my site -- http://www.todddudley.com -- if you click on "Services" at the top you will see that it makes the whole nav bar come down. I want it to look like this -- http://www.gracemaryville.org --.

Here is the script:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#flip").click(function(){
$("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
</script>
```

and here is the html:

```
<div id="flip">Services</div>
<div id="panel">
<div id="inside">
<a href="http://www.todddudley.com.com/">Logo Design</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you help? I would like to use HTML and CSS only but I will use JavaScript to, as that's what I used here.

Thanks!

"-- example --" is a link.

Comment: Show some code, so we can help you - anyways you only need javascript for the fade-in effect. All othre things are possible with HTML and CSS only.

Comment: Neither URL works, can you format your question, and add some code?

Comment: please post code here and don't shorten urls as they could be spam, you maybe could do with reading the help section about how to ask a good question

Comment: thanks I'm very new to the site.

Answer (score 0):

this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/)
horizontal menu  css and html only

Comment: I don't see how that helps. I don't know how to properly code it this is just a simulator. I think you may have missed something.

Comment: this is great, but if you move the mouse to slow it goes away before you can click any thing.

Comment: Use transition: all 0.3s;

Comment: where would I put that?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I could not get it right. It did not match the rest of the site at all.